# shell script to read each line and run the condition

Tags: shell

I have a log file which has the below data

```
120
140
200
110
200
200
120
90
100
```

I want to read this file and compare each line(number) with 200, and if it crosses 200 - then it has to compare the next word till the 5 consecutive which crosses 200 then it has to send a alert otherwise script has to end.

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: if 5 continuous numbers which are more than 200, it has to send alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to detect when 5 consecutive rows contain a value greater than 200?  If so:

```
awk '{a = $1 > lim ? a + 1 : 0}
    a > seq {print "alert on line " NR}' lim=200 seq=5 input
```

It's not clear what you actually want, and perhaps you want to use `>=` rather than `>` in the above.

This simply reads through the file named `input` and checks if the number is greater than 200 (the value given to `lim`).  If it is, it increments a counter.  When that counter is greater than `seq`, it prints a message.

Comment: The consecutive 5 rows(more than 200) can be in the middle or at the end. we need to find out those if they are - then it should say True otherwise False. And if possible- we need to find the highest one in the 5